# ActivePerl ppm issue on Windows 7, installed modules cannot be verified

Tags: perl, cpan, activeperl

My ppm was working a few days ago when I installed a number of email related modules, it installs and verifies every module just fine. But now it has an issue, let me give you an example:

> ppm install email::simple
>
> No missing packages to install
>
> ppm verify email::simple
>
> ppm verify failed: Package 'email::simple' is not installed

I tested with a script I wrote that uses this module and it compile and runs just fine. However, it didn't work out for another module I installed later.

> ppm install email::received
>
> No missing packages to install
>
> ppm verify email::received
>
> ppm verify failed: Package 'email::received' is not installed
>
> perl test.pl "FILE"
>
> Can't locate Eamil/Received.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at test.pl line 17.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 17.

I verified myself that the file received.pm was installed under Perl64/site/lib/email/. Why is compiler not recognizing this module?

PS: I can also see the email::received module was installed with the GUI ppm. I tried re-installing ActivePerl but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

```
Can't locate Eamil/...
```

"Eamil" should be "Email". Fix your incorrect `use` statement.

---

As for your inability to verify installs, `verify` expects `ppm verify Email-Received`.

Comment: I don't see how did I spell incorrectly when verifying modules. capitalization doesn't change the result. What you see in my post is what I got form the CLI

Comment: You only mentioned the irrelevant. What happened after you fixed the misspelling in `test.pl`?

Comment: Updated node to indicate the actual reason `verify` doesn't work.